# Boost link error occurs even though I'm including the library

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to build a boost-dependent project on TravisCI. When it runs [the `g++` command](https://travis-ci.org/aaronj1335/cs388-final-project/builds/23770575#L855):

```
g++ -Wall -L/usr/lib -fopenmp -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -o bin/test obj/data_parser.o obj/hmm.o obj/test.o
```

It gets [this linking error](https://travis-ci.org/aaronj1335/cs388-final-project/builds/23770575#L857):

```
data_parser.cpp:(.text+0x136a): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
```

But not only am I including `-lboost_system` in the `g++` command, I also know that [`/usr/lib/libboost_system.so` exists](https://travis-ci.org/aaronj1335/cs388-final-project/builds/23770575#L208).

This is on an Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5 system with g++ 4.6.3. I installed the boost libraries with:

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-dev libboost-filesystem1.46-dev libboost-iostreams1.46-dev libboost-system1.46-dev
```

**Why won't this link correctly?**

Comment: put the -l options for boost *after* the .o files. It's a linker thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the libraries after the object files in the linker command.

The objects and libraries are linked in order; and library code is only linked if it's needed to resolve a reference in the currently linked objects. By putting them first, there are no unresolved references when they are processed, so no code is linked from them.

Comment: thanks! i was thrown off because this worked with g++-4.8 when the boost files were *.a files, but not g++-4.6 and *.so files, so is that something that might have changed in the new version? or does it have to do with the file format?